# Matlab CREEPS me out. Are there more "Ghosts"?

Tags: matlab

So, I was happily coding my stuff with my long runtime codes and I made some minnor mistake in plot handling. This happened:

[image]

I was really astonished, as you could guess. Googling around I found out that it is the default "image" handle when using `get()`.

So my question is, are there any more of this fantastically creeping stuff in Matlab? Which ones?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2001-what-matlab-easter-eggs-do-you-know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, have you ever asked yourself why all that?

```
>> why 
The bald and not excessively bald and not excessively smart hamster
obeyed a terrified and not excessively terrified hamster.
```

Comment: "To please the tall engineer"

Comment: The corresponding help (there is one!) is hilarious: `Provides succinct answers to almost any question.
    why, by itself, provides a random answer.
    why(N) provides the N-th answer.
    Please embellish or modify this function to suit your own tastes.`

Comment: Ok, please see the code of `why`: it's really a random generator of sentences, worth a look. And you paid for that ... :D

Answer (score 2):

That is Steve Eddins' son. Steve is one of the lead developers on MathWorks Image Processing team. See [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/17/the-story-behind-the-matlab-default-image/) for the story - and to find out about a lot more hidden images.

Try typing `spy` as well, with no input arguments :)

Comment: WOW, the image is WAY more complex that it seems